# How to view all my comment votes in Disqus?

Tags: comments, profile, disqus

There's a comment I want to find that I upvoted a long time ago on Disqus. I can't remember what it said exactly, so I'm having a rough time searching for it. The only thing I can think of to do is to view all my votes that I've made on comments. Yet, I see no way to do this by browsing my Disqus profile. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: kind of not possible

Comment: @user0 Why? Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I just tested it and it looks like there isnt a way to do this

Comment: @user0 Hmm, that's really too bad. Where can I file a ticket to Disqus to ask them about adding this feature?

Comment: here: https://disqus.com/home/channel/discussdisqus/